# importing data from excel file to c#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I have an excel file:    City         Cafe           Phone Number
                       New York     Trio Cafe          78654
                       New York     Central Cafe       32344
                      Washington    House Cafe         23222
                      Washington    Central Cafe       11111
                         LA         Wood Cafe          45434
                        Texas       Central Cafe       16564

ComboBox1 contains cities.
ComboBox2 contains cafes.
Button1 writes to datagridview.
My problem is that:
For Example: I am choosing Washington in the ComboBox1.Then I am choosing Central Cafe in the Combobox2 and clicking Button1.
I see  that:      New York     Central Cafe       32344
                 Washington    Central Cafe       11111
                 Texas         Central Cafe       16564
in the datagridview.
But I chose Washington in the Combobox1.So I want to see only
                  Washington    Central Cafe       11111
in the datagridview.

How can I do this??

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
namespace uy
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    OleDbConnection baglan = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\users\\toshiba\\desktop\\proje-1; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection baglan = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\users\\toshiba\\desktop\\proje-1; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");

        baglan.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT  * FROM [Sheet1$A1:A1000]";
        OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand(sql, baglan);
        OleDbDataReader dr = null;
        dr = komut.ExecuteReader();



        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(dr[0].ToString()))
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
            }


        }
        baglan.Close();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Clear();

        OleDbConnection baglan = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\users\\toshiba\\desktop\\proje-1; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");
        baglan.Open();
        string sql_b = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B1:B1000]";
        OleDbCommand komut_b = new OleDbCommand(sql_b, baglan);
        OleDbDataReader dr_b = null;
        dr_b = komut_b.ExecuteReader();

        string sql_a = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:A1000]";
        OleDbCommand komut_a = new OleDbCommand(sql_a, baglan);
        OleDbDataReader dr_a = null;
        dr_a = komut_a.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr_a.Read() && dr_b.Read())
        {
            if (dr_a[0].ToString() == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                if (!comboBox2.Items.Contains(dr_b[0].ToString()))
                {
                    comboBox2.Items.Add(dr_b[0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        baglan.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM[Sheet1$]  where Cafe like '%" + comboBox2.SelectedItem + "%'", baglan);
        dt.Clear();
        baglan.Open();

        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        baglan.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: First thing is  no need of multiple declarations of OLEDB baglan, second Use Parametrised queries.

Comment: Could you show me the code, I have no idea how do this.

Comment: new code is below but not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like,

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox2.Items.Clear();
    OleDbConnection baglan = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\users\\toshiba\\desktop\\proje-1; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");
    baglan.Open();
    string sql_b = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] where [city]=@city";        
    OleDbCommand komut_b = new OleDbCommand(sql_b, baglan);
    komut_b.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", comboBox1.Text.ToString());
    OleDbDataReader dr_b = null;
    dr_b = komut_b.ExecuteReader();        
    while (dr_b.Read())
    {           
      comboBox2.Items.Add(dr_b[0].ToString());                
    }
    baglan.Close();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 OleDbConnection baglan = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\users\\toshiba\\desktop\\proje-1; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");
OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter dAdpter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);
comm.Connection = baglan;
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM[Sheet1$]  where Cafe like @cafe and city =@city";   
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cafe", "%" + comboBox2.Text.ToString() + "%"); 
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city",combobox1.Text.ToString());
dAdpter.Fill(dt);
 datagridview.DataSource=dt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks foe helping but """""komut_b.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", +comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString());"""""" line is error. I  removed + and it is fixed. But when program is run, I can choose city but combobox2 is empty, I can't choose cafe.

Comment: @OsmanFurkanYılmaz yes,that was a typo, I have changed the selected text to text propery for combobox. this should work now. You can set a breakpoint to see if query is correctly framed.Feel free to ask if there is any problem.

Comment: I am sorry, you can call me Beginner. But I don't understand, How can I fix this. Combobox2 is empty while the program is run. What is the correct version of code, thanks

Comment: @OsmanFurkanYılmaz Combobox2 will be filled when you change the index in combox1, see the code for loading combobox2 is written in selectedindex changed event. if you want to load it at form load, you can change the index of combobox1 (like combox1.SelectedIndex =1 )at form load so the event is fired or call the method at form load.

Answer (score 0):

I reorganized like that but now when the program run, I can choose city and cafe but When I clicked the button, datagridview is empty.

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Clear();

        OleDbConnection baglan = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\users\\toshiba\\desktop\\proje-1; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");
        baglan.Open();

        string sql_a = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] where [City]=@City";
        OleDbCommand komut_a = new OleDbCommand(sql_a, baglan);
        komut_a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        OleDbDataReader dr_a = null;
        dr_a = komut_a.ExecuteReader();
        string sql_b = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B1:B1000]";
        OleDbCommand komut_b = new OleDbCommand(sql_b, baglan);
        OleDbDataReader dr_b = null;
        dr_b = komut_b.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr_a.Read() && dr_b.Read())
        {
            if (dr_a[0].ToString() == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                if (!comboBox2.Items.Contains(dr_b[0].ToString()))
                {
                    comboBox2.Items.Add(dr_b[0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        baglan.Close();


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbConnection baglan = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\users\\toshiba\\desktop\\proje-1; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");
       OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();
 OleDbDataAdapter dAdpter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);
comm.Connection = baglan;
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM[Sheet1$]  where Cafe like '%@Dormitory%'";
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cafe",    comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());

        dAdpter.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        baglan.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Use, comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM[Sheet1$]  where Cafe like @cafe";   
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cafe", "%" + comboBox2.Text.ToString() + "%");

Comment: no, again  I saw every central cafe line in the datagridview like my first code.

Comment: because  "SELECT * FROM[Sheet1$]  where Cafe like '%@Dormitory%'" should be SELECT * FROM[Sheet1$]  where Cafe like '%@Dormitory% and city =@city, i.e you are not filtering on basis of city. see the edited code in my answer,i Have done so.